# RTFD Data Equality Check

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nstextview

I'm using the function below to set new **rtfd data** to an attribute of type binary in a core data entity.

If its not equal, then I set the data to the managed object.

The problem here is that the equality only works when the **rtfd data** is only text. When there are pictures attached this method is returning false.

```
-(BOOL)setRTFData:(NSData*)data forKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSData *actualData = [self getDataValueForKey:key];

    NSDictionary *dict = nil;
    NSAttributedString *actualAttribString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTFD:actualData documentAttributes:&dict];
    NSAttributedString *newAttribString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTFD:data documentAttributes:&dict];

    BOOL isEqual = [actualAttribString isEqualToAttributedString:newAttribString];
    [actualAttribString release];
    [newAttribString release];

    if (!isEqual) 
    {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:key];
        [self setPrimitiveValue:data forKey:key];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:key];

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

this is how I get my **rtfd data**from a `NSTextView`:

```
NSData* data = [notesTextField RTFDFromRange:NSMakeRange(0,[[notesTextField textStorage] length])];
```

I'm using sdk 10.7

Comment: Why not just compare the two `NSData` objects directly? Is there a reason for doing the comparision with `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: In my tests, comparing nsdata directly does not always return true, even when they are the same. If its only text, the rtfd data check works, but not when pictures are added